# Clipping Bubble?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

I was wondering if it is possible to use geometry as a view clipping boundary? For example, could I use a sphere to clip the boundary of other geometry, which would then auto-update as I move the sphere? My hope is to avoid using the boolean modifier as it is processing heavy on complex geometry.

Best,
Niko

Comment: Maybe change the Clip End value in the View tab of the 3D viewport. Or perhaps give the sphere a Holdout material. (it depends on what exactly you want to achieve though.)